# Fetching more thatn 10000 documents from Elasticsearch in Spring too slow

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index with some more than 20 000 documents, initially i fetched the documents with

```
final SearchHits<MyTyp> searchHitsMyTyp =
        elasticsearchCustomTemplate.search(
                searchQueryMyTyp,
                MyTyp.class,
                IndexCoordinates.of(indexSettings.indexMyTypName))
```

and it returned 10 000 documents immediately , so to handle the limitation i have chnaged that code to the following to fetch all records

```
 NativeSearchQuery searchQuery =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(
                        QueryBuilders.matchQuery(
                                "MyTyp_id", mytyp.getId()))
                .build();
                
NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("MyTyp_id"", mytyp.getId()));
queryBuilder.withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000));
queryBuilder.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("_id").order(SortOrder.ASC));


queryBuilder.withAggregations(
        AggregationBuilders.filter(
                "filter_by_id", QueryBuilders.termQuery("MyTyp_id", mytyp.getId())));
NativeSearchQuery searchQueryMyTyp = queryBuilder.build();
SearchHit[] searchHitsMyTyp=null;
final ArrayList<MyTyp> typeList=new ArrayList();

do {
  if(searchHitsMyTyp!=null) {
    searchQuery.setSearchAfter(searchHitsMyTyp[searchHitsMyTyp.length - 1].getSortValues().stream().toList());
  }
  searchHitsMyTyp =  elasticsearchCustomTemplate.search(
          searchQueryMyTyp,
          MyTyp.class,
          IndexCoordinates.of(indexSettings.indexMyTypName)).getSearchHits().toArray(new SearchHit[0]);
  typeList.addAll( Arrays.stream(searchHitsMyTyp).map(p->(MyTyp)p.getContent()).toList());


}while(searchHitsMyTyp.length >= 10000);
```

now the problem is that its so slows that it literally hangs the UI, is there a way to make that calls faster ,
so if returning 10000 results takes 1 sec 20000 should take like 2 sec ,not sure if there is actually a way arround that or its limitation of ElasticSearch and Spring ?

Comment: Why do you want to display 20000 hits on a page? Instead display 10-100 docs at a time and paginate.

Comment: actually on the page i need to display the size of that  querry hits , so i just display the number 20000

Comment: If you want to paginate, then you need to get a count of the records the query will return, work out how many pages there are and then fetch X records per page. Alternatively, you use scrolling and in that case you can just fetch records in smaller chunks - a couple of tens or hundreds at a time. 10,000 records seems a lot to work with/scroll through for a user interface.

Comment: It's better to display first the meaningful documents to the user (the most relevant ones) instead of letting the user paginate 2000 times to find the right information they are looking for.